# How to calculate string 2*2+6/3+6

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I want to make calculator. I don't know to split the string and calculate the result. Is there any algorithm or some easy way to get result? I have already searched for it. But it only tells infix expressions.

Comment: please add what you have already tried and how we can help you. a code sample might help.
it sounds a bit like you want us to do your homework

Answer (score 1):

### **Using an External Library**

I Google searched the term "android library for calculating math expressions in strings" and the first result was: http://mathparser.org/

If you go to that link and scroll down a bit, it actually shows an animation of how it works. There also seems to be plenty of tutorials.

### **Creating your own Algorithm**

Whilst using an external library in this case certainly does seem to be the optimal option, if you were required to develop the algorithm yourself the use of BODMAS (or PEMDAS depending where you are from) will be critical. At least in your case however, brackets and orders would not be needed.

Your algorithm could initially iterate the string for all cases of division e.g. where the character '/' is found, then multiplication '*', then addition '+' and finally subtraction '-'.

For each case the operands would be the digits to the left and right of the operator. Then replace the immediate expression with the calculation in the overall expression.

So the steps of your recursive style algorithm may look like the following:

- 2*2+6/3+6
- 2*2+2+6
- 4+2+6
- 6+6
- 12

Some things you'll need to be able to do:

- Convert a character to the expected integer ( hint: subtract '0' or 48 )
- Consider if your operands will be longer than one character e.g. 10 (look into substrings)
- Possibly think about performance improvement 
  e.g. 4+2+6 could be calculated in one step rather than two